# Find how many flight connections a city has by using graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

There are 12 direct flight routes between 7 major cities. There are 4 flight roots starting from or ending at cities D, F, G and 2 starting from or ending at C, E. City B has flight connections to D, E, G only. Find how many flight connections city A has?

Answer (score 0):

We can think of the major cites as vertices and the direct flight routes as edges between the vertices. The number of flight routes from or ending in a specific city would be the degree of that vertex.

We know that the sum of all the degrees of the vertices in a graph is equal to twice the number of edges in the graph. So the number of edges in this graph is $12$, so therefore the sum of the degrees will add up to $24$.

The degree of $D, F,$ and $G$ is $4$, $C$ and $E$ is $2$, and $B$ would have degree $3$ since it has $3$ connections, and lets say $A$ has degree $x$.

So 
$$4+4+4+2+2+3+x=24$$
$$19+x=24$$
$$x=5$$

Therefore we know that $A$ has degree $5$, so that means city $A$ has $5$ flight connections.

Comment: Spot on and thank you very much for the detail explanation. You are great and I am confident to handle similar questions in future.